# EACCES: permission denied open '[file]' error on OSX Electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

Please help me understand what I need to change to fix the above error, **EACCES: permission denied open "file.json"** after I package my Electron app and run it on a Mac.

Running the app locally produces no errors, and I suspect there are some permissions that are not being checked locally. However, I do not have a clue to what I might need to change - the linked SO questions about EACCES: permission denied are related *solely* to NPM modules, which my code is not.

To demonstrate, I have the following code which works fine locally:

```
const fs = require("fs");

// Create file if not exist
if (!fs.existsSync("file.json")){
    fs.writeFileSync("file.json", "", function(error){
        if (error){
            console.error("could not write new key");
        }
    });
}
```

After bundling with [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder), running the application shows the error **EACCES: permission denied open "file.json"**.

I am [using a relative file path](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths) as the documentation suggests. I've also tried setting **"asar": false** [documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration) -- to show the unpackaged electron app in my file system, and every user has full access.
[image]

Comment: Have you considered writing your file to the "user data" directory? (e.g. the MacOS equivalent of `C:\Users\{user}\AppData`) This is generally how you avoid having elevated permissions as certain areas are read/write restricted to non-admin users or users without elevated permissions (e.g. run as admin).

Comment: You are correct, that is the proper way to do it. My solution is based on this author's post. I refactored my code to use a class he describes and the error is gone, thank you @JakeHolzinger. https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/how-to-store-user-data-in-electron-3ba6bf66bc1e